# Is it possible to use a string variable consisting of HTML within a Blazor page using a Bootstrap modal window?

Tags: blazor, bootstrap-5, asp.net-core-5.0

I have a Blazor page that creates a pop-up using Bootstrap 5's modal functionality.

Within that modal there is a form that communicates with a server. If the action is successful I get back a `200` response. Depending on whether or not I get the `200`, I want to show a different message.

**MyPage.razor**

```
<div>

    <!-- ... -->

    <div class="modal fade" id="id" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="label" aria-hidden="true">

        <!-- ... -->

        @resultMessage

        <!-- ... -->

    </div>

    <!-- ... -->

</div>

@code {
    private String resultMessage;

    public void doSomething(){
        resultMessage = is200Success ? "<div class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\">Query Saved</div>" : "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\">Query Not Saved</div>";
    }
}
```

However, when the message shows up, it looks like this:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Query Saved</div>
```

Meaning, I can see the HTML and not the pretty [Bootstrap alert](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/alerts/).

I tried using `@((MarkupString)resultMessage)` on the page, but it put the alert on the actual page, and not within my modal window.

Comment: check https://mudblazor.com/components/snackbar , if you dont like to use bootsrap

Comment: Casting to MarkupString is of course the solution. Post that code to resolve why it didn't show up right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some more googling, I came up with this that works for me:

```
resultMessage = is200Success ? @<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Query Saved</div> : @<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Query Not Saved</div>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
<div>
    <!-- ... -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="id" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="label" aria-hidden="true">
        <!-- ... -->
        @if (showMessage) 
            {
            <div class="@css" role="alert">
            @message
            </div>
            }
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>

@code 
{
private String resultMessage;

private bool showMessage = false;
privare bool success = true;
private string message = success ? "Query Saved": "Query Not Saved";
private string css = success ? "alert alert-success": "alert alert-danger";

public void doSomething(){
    success = is200Success;
    showMessage = true;
}
}
```

I haven't run the code so there may be a typo or two!